# Accessing Keychain in sandboxed application under Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, macos, cocoa, keychain

I've been successfully using `SecItemAdd()` and `SecItemCopyMatching()` functions to store and retrieve Keychain information in iOS and OS X Lion (sandboxed). These functions are in iOS since 2.x and in OS X since 10.6 (Snow Leopard), so I figured out that I should be able to use the very same code on Snow Leopard as well.

Unfortunately, under Snow Leopard I can't access encrypted data (passwords) in a keychain item with `SecItemCopyMatching()`, only usernames, addresses etc. are visible. I tried to retrieve keychain items with the OS X-specific `SecKeychainFindInternetPassword()` function and it's a little bit more descriptive as it gives me `errSecAuthFailed (-25293)` error.

Interestingly enough, when sandboxing is turned off `SecItemAdd()`/`SecItemCopyMatching()` works well under Snow Leopard. Also, the `SecKeychainAddInternetPassword()` / `SecKeychainFindInternetPassword()` pair works fine with and without sandboxing. However, I'd really like to be able to use the same code in iOS and OS X and according to docs/API it should be possible.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I reported the issue to Apple and they confirmed that it's a bug. You just have to use the old APIs on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Yep, that's what worked for me as well.